# Understanding Promises/A+ and how Asynchronicity works with Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, es6-promise

I am a complete newbie in this sort of JavaScript programming, some of my question might look to stupid for you and you might role your eyes but please bear with me.

Lately I was reading and implementing a tutorial about [Spring Boot and React](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/react-and-spring-data-rest/). In this tutorial, the author was using a library called rest (package.json - "rest": "^1.3.1") and mentioning it is a  [Promies/A+](https://promisesaplus.com/) based library is.

I try to implement the tutorial but I have other type datastructure then the tutorial, more in a Tree structure, so the consequence I have to make one Rest call and with the solution of first call I have to make another Rest call, there I have the behavior I can't explain, call looks like the following (als Pseudo code).

```
client({method: 'GET', path: 'http://localhost:8080/service1'})
    .then(response =>{
       this.setState({result1 : response.entity._embedded.systems})
       return this.state.systems;
    })
    .then(function(results1) {
        {
            results1 && results1.map(
                function(result) {
                   client({method: 'GET', path: result._links.services.href })
                   .done( response => {
                      var results2 = response.entity._embedded.services
                      result.services = results2;
                    });
                }
            )
        }
    }
    );
```

Now my problem this 2 then(..) blocks runs completely asynchronous, actually I am using React and the moment I call the this.setState(....) react renders the component while only the result from the first call is there, while setup this code on 'componentDidMount()', I am expecting that 'render()' will only start when the execution of the 'componentDidMount()' ended.

I tried to make second Rest Service call in the first 'then(...)' block but that didn't changed anything.

```
 client({method: 'GET', path: 'http://localhost:8080/service1'})
    .then(response =>{
       var tmp = response.entity._embedded.systems;
       tmp && tmp.map(
          function(result) {
              client({method: 'GET', path: result._links.services.href })
                 .done( response => {
                    var results2 = response.entity._embedded.services
                    result.services = results2;
                  });
               }
       this.setState({result1 : response.entity._embedded.systems})
    })
```

same behavior, the results from first Rest call but nothing from 2nd.

At the end, to make this work I made the following,

```
setTimeout(
   function() {
      this.setState({result1: tmp});
   }
)
```

but this can't be the correct way of doing this.

So my question is, what am I doing wrong and what I can do better?

Thx for answers....

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps a bit. I commented my changes

```
client({method: 'GET', path: 'http://localhost:8080/service1'})
.then(response =>{
   this.setState({result1 : response.entity._embedded.systems})
   return this.state.systems;
})
.then(function(results1) {
        var promises = results1.map(
            function(result) {  // return the created promise
               return client({method: 'GET', path: result._links.services.href })
               .done( response => {
                  var results2 = response.entity._embedded.services
                  result.services = results2;
                });
            }
        )
        return Promise.all(promises) // return promiseCollection
    }
});
```

[edit:]
You can pass a array of promises into promise.all. It will wait until all promises are fulfilled and then call its then() methode.

Comment: First, thx for the answer, but can you explain me what I will achieve with this :)? Will 'Promise.all(promises)' be a synchronization point or so?